# Python - xml extraction with multi duplicated tags

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some coordinate out of a xml file.The thing is my xml file have multi same tags so I can't correctly isolate them.

Say the xml is something like this:

```
<GeoFeature gml:id="0">
<Vertices>
<Vertex IndexNo="0" srsDimension="3">649277.148852   5142325.926182 -955.329113</Vertex>
<Vertex IndexNo="1" srsDimension="3">649262.401411   5142320.847273  -955.159828</Vertex>
<Vertex IndexNo="2" srsDimension="3">649271.562070   5142318.588838  -955.413264</Vertex>
<Vertex IndexNo="3" srsDimension="3">649273.811729   5142318.034215  -955.486051</Vertex>
</Vertices>
</GeoFeature gml:id="0">
<GeoFeature gml:id="1">
<Vertices>
<Vertex IndexNo="0" srsDimension="3">649277.148852   5142325.926182  -955.329113</Vertex>
<Vertex IndexNo="1" srsDimension="3">649262.401411   5142320.847273  -955.159828</Vertex>
<Vertex IndexNo="2" srsDimension="3">649271.562070   5142318.588838  -955.413264</Vertex>
<Vertex IndexNo="3" srsDimension="3">649273.811729   5142318.034215  -955.486051</Vertex>
</Vertices>
</GeoFeature gml:id="1">
```

then all I need to do is very simple

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup (open xml)
results = []

def get_data_vaule():
    GeoFeatures=soup.find_all('GeoFeature')
    for GeoFeature in GeoFeatures:
        if GeoFeature['gml:id'] = 0:
            vertexs=soup.find_all('Vertex')    
            for vertex in vertexs:
                value=vertex.contents
                for i in value:
                    str(i)
                    results.append(i)
```

that str at last is to get rid of all () and []  leave only coordinate.

But the actual xml file is very complicate, about 2,000,000 lines, even VS can't fold each part so I never really get a clear picture of it's structure.

For example, the actual path to `<Vertex>`   is :

tree.xpath("./GeoModel/FeatureClasses/FeatureClass/GeoFeatureClass/Features/Feature/GeoFeature/Geometry/Shape/GeoTin/Vertices/Vertex")

The problem is there are multi parts with `gml:id="0"` and `gml:id="1"` etc.

So far I can't find any certain labels to isolate each part.

And I have to isolate them because under the `<Vertex>` is `<Triangle>` like this:

```
<Triangle IndexNo="9613">
<VertexList>5253 5426 5425</VertexList>
<NeighborList>9618 9934 9614</NeighborList>
</Triangle>
```

The `<VertexList>` is start from 1 and reset to 1 in each parts. 
Thus, isolate first then extract coordinate is necessary.

Any ideas?